# Search an array for matching attribute

Tags: javascript

I have an array, I need to return a restaurant's name, but I only know the value of its "food" attribute (not it's index number).

For example, how could I return "KFC" if I only knew "chicken"?

```
restaurants = 
  [
    {"restaurant" : { "name" : "McDonald's", "food" : "burger" }},
    {"restaurant" : { "name" : "KFC",        "food" : "chicken" }},
    {"restaurant" : { "name" : "Pizza Hut",  "food" : "pizza" }}
  ];
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Ok, but when you use this library https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20160212, you'll see that it contains `org.json.JSONObject`. Of course, this is a class and what you are referring to is a concept.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0; i < restaurants.length; i++)
{
  if(restaurants[i].restaurant.food == 'chicken')
  {
    return restaurants[i].restaurant.name;
  }
}
```

Comment: For some speed improvement change first line to:

`for(var i = 0, numRestaurants = restaurants.length; i < numRestaurants, i++)`

Comment: @AntonySastre: Semi colon missing: `for(var i = 0, numRestaurants = restaurants.length; i < numRestaurants; i++)`

Comment: @AntonySastre why is that a speed improvement?

Comment: because restaurants.length will be accessed over and over until the loop ends, unlike when stored in a variable, it will only get the value that is already set.

Comment: I don't think so... Isn't length a property of Array (an object)? Array.length should have constant time complexity. Wouldn't most js engines understand what you're trying to do and optimize around it?

Answer (score 81):

you can also use the `Array.find` feature of `es6`. the doc is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
return restaurants.find(item => {
   return item.restaurant.food == 'chicken'
})
```

Comment: At the moment, this feels like the most elegant solution.

Comment: The find() method is a better option to use across modern browsers, but if you care about the IE browser, use the filter() method.

Comment: Shouldn't the code snippet be like `return restaurants.find(item => { return item.restaurant.food == 'chicken' }).name;` since the OP wants to have "KFC" returned, not the whole object?

Answer (score 53):

In this case i would use the ECMAscript 5 Array.filter. The following solution requires array.filter() that doesn't exist in all versions of IE.

Shims can be found here: [MDN Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [ES5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)

```
var result = restaurants.filter(function (chain) {
    return chain.restaurant.food === "chicken";
})[0].restaurant.name;
```

Comment: This is superior to the accept answer because it points out that there can potentially be more than one match.  In this case, the code returns the first match via `[0]`, but filter actually returns them all.  However, it will not work with IE 6, 7, and 8.  But hey, screw IE 6, 7, and 8.

Answer (score 9):

```
for (x in restaurants) {
    if (restaurants[x].restaurant.food == 'chicken') {
        return restaurants[x].restaurant.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does this have -1 beside it

Comment: Not sure, the code works perfectly.  It may be waiting for your +1.

Comment: Because it's slow when compared to a standard for() loop. See [Javascript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#object.forinloop) for more info.

Comment: for in should not be used for arrays

Comment: I agree with pjnovas. For-in is dangerous. If array gets a prototype, this code will fail. Example: Run "Array.prototype.f = function(){};" before the for-in.

Comment: `hasOwnProperty()` can be added to address the above concerns: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 9):

```
let restaurant = restaurants.find(element => element.restaurant.food == "chicken");
```

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the
> provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

as you can see in [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 3):

Must be too late now, but the right version would be:

```
for(var i = 0; i < restaurants.restaurant.length; i++)
{
  if(restaurants.restaurant[i].food == 'chicken')
  {
    return restaurants.restaurant[i].name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use ES5 some. Its pretty first by using callback

```
function findRestaurent(foodType) {
    var restaurant;
    restaurants.some(function (r) {
        if (r.food === id) {
            restaurant = r;
            return true;
        }
   });
  return restaurant;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Chap - you can use this javascript lib, DefiantJS (http://defiantjs.com), with which you can filter matches using XPath on JSON structures. To put it in JS code:

```
var data = [
   { "restaurant": { "name": "McDonald's", "food": "burger" } },
   { "restaurant": { "name": "KFC",        "food": "chicken" } },
   { "restaurant": { "name": "Pizza Hut",  "food": "pizza" } }
].
res = JSON.search( data, '//*[food="pizza"]' );

console.log( res[0].name );
// Pizza Hut
```

DefiantJS extends the global object with the method "search" and returns an array with matches (empty array if no matches were found). You can try out the lib and XPath queries using the XPath Evaluator here:

http://www.defiantjs.com/#xpath_evaluator