# Parse JSON into subsets

Tags: javascript, json

The following is my JSON string and I would like to parse it on the client side into the 3 different column names (MAT_ETHNICITY, PAT_ETHNICITY, SEX) so I can put the values into a drop down list for each column.  Should I just do three separate SQL calls and send it via three different server calls, parse it Server side or parse it client side by looping? Thanks

```
[
    {
        "REFCODE": "HIS",
        "DESCRIPTION": "Hispanic or Latino",
        "COLUMN_NAME": "MAT_ETHNICITY"
    },
    {
        "REFCODE": "NHIS",
        "DESCRIPTION": "Not Hispanic or Latino",
        "COLUMN_NAME": "MAT_ETHNICITY"
    },
    {
        "REFCODE": "UNK",
        "DESCRIPTION": "Unknown",
        "COLUMN_NAME": "MAT_ETHNICITY"
    },
    {
        "REFCODE": "AMERIND",
        "DESCRIPTION": "American Indian/Alaska Native",
        "COLUMN_NAME": "PAT_ETHNICITY"
    },
    {
        "REFCODE": "ASIAN",
        "DESCRIPTION": "Asian",
        "COLUMN_NAME": "PAT_ETHNICITY"
    },
    {
        "REFCODE": "HAW",
        "DESCRIPTION": "Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander",
        "COLUMN_NAME": "PAT_ETHNICITY"
    },
    {
        "REFCODE": "AA",
        "DESCRIPTION": "Black or Africian American",
        "COLUMN_NAME": "PAT_ETHNICITY"
    },
    {
        "REFCODE": "WHITE",
        "DESCRIPTION": "White",
        "COLUMN_NAME": "PAT_ETHNICITY"
    },
    {
        "REFCODE": "MORE",
        "DESCRIPTION": "More than one race",
        "COLUMN_NAME": "PAT_ETHNICITY"
    },
    {
        "REFCODE": "UNK",
        "DESCRIPTION": "Unknown",
        "COLUMN_NAME": "PAT_ETHNICITY"
    },
    {
        "REFCODE": "M",
        "DESCRIPTION": "Male",
        "COLUMN_NAME": "SEX"
    },
    {
        "REFCODE": "F",
        "DESCRIPTION": "Female",
        "COLUMN_NAME": "SEX"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make use of array mapping:

```
var refArr = jsonObj.map(function(ele){return ele.REFCODE;})
var descArr = jsonObj.map(function(ele){return ele.DESCRIPTION;})
var colNameArr = jsonObj.map(function(ele){return ele.COLUMN_NAME;})
```

Each map call will iterate through the JSON array you are returning, and then grab the values and put them into their corresponding array.

---

EDIT:
However, based on your comments I believe we all assumed you were asking something different than what you wanted. Your comments

> ... SEX, PAT_ENTICITY and MAT_ETHNICITY and not the REFCODE, DESCRIPTION and COLUMN_NAME. So I would end up with sexArr = ["Female","Male"] and MAT_ETHNICITY would be var matArr=["Hispanic or Latino", "Not Hispanic or Latino"] etc? or is looping the best

You *could* [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for those value arrays, but you would have to strip undefined or empty string values if you used mapping since mapping will return the same number of elements as are found in the array you are mapping from.

You would want to iterate through it with [.forEach(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) similar to the following:

```
var sexArr = [];
var patArr = [];
var matArr = [];

jsonObj.forEach(function(ele){
  switch(ele.COLUMN_NAME){
    case "SEX":
      sexArr.push(ele.DESCRIPTION);
      break;
    case "PAT_ETHNICITY":
      patArr.push(ele.DESCRIPTION);
      break;
    case "MAT_ETHNICITY":
      matArr.push(ele.DESCRIPTION);
      break;
    default:
      //do nothing, or handle as you see fit.
      break;
  }
});
```

This code produces the following based on the array you gave:

```
//matArr
["Hispanic or Latino", "Not Hispanic or Latino", "Unknown"]

//patArr
["American Indian/Alaska Native", "Asian", "Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander", "Black or Africian American", "White", "More than one race", "Unknown"]

//sexArr
["Male", "Female"]
```

Comment: If the array is really big, it's probably better to loop just once. Also, this will give you duplicates

Comment: Good call, I think it is useful to explore the functional programming nature of Javascript so I kept the `.map in`, but added a `.forEach` after reading your comment, so it'd only iterate the loop once. Based on the nature of the fact he is making drop downs I would hope the array wouldn't be too large.

Comment: The OP doesn't mention stripping duplicates though.

Comment: Not explicitly, but they do mention putting the options in a drop down. Would you want a drop down with duplicate options?

Comment: You all have given very good information.  For the record- duplicates would be handles with the server side select statement, but having the ability to handle on client side is a nice plus. Filling the drop downs is not an issue but I wanted to describe how and why I needed three separate arrays.  The original question about Server Side was only so if someone said "This is not something that client side is intendent to do and for best practices go back to the server I would understand.

Comment: The size of the data may be 10-15 items at most, never very big. I realize that I could on the server create three separate JSON objects and send them at one time and parse the arrays but I was hoping and did get some very good information that I will use in many different ways.  a VERY BIG THANK YOU TO ALL. I know that I will return a number of times to leverage all of this information.

Comment: Arty-Can I use .map to split it into three arrays of SEX, PAT_ENTICITY and MAT_ETHNICITY and not the REFCODE, DESCRIPTION and COLUMN_NAME.  So I would end up with sexArr = ["Female","Male"] and MAT_ETHNICITY would be var matArr=["Hispanic or Latino", "Not Hispanic or Latino"] etc? or is looping the best?

Comment: you could map, but it would be better to iterate in that case, I added code to demonstrate. Advantage of using array.prototype built in methods for iterating is that it is less code and logic for you, and if performance isn't an issue it becomes a simpler task and less variables to keep track of.

Comment: You're welcome, when you get the chance please don't forget to select the response you found most helpful as your answer and/or upvote the ones you found helpful as well. Best regards with the rest of your code :)

Answer (score 1):

You should minimize the number of calls to the server to help speed your site up. Parsing this into three different arrays is easy enough to do in JavaScript.

```
var data = [...], // This is the array you have up top
    refCodes = [],
    descriptions = [],
    columns = [],
    parseData;

parseData = function () {
    var ref,
        desc,
        col,
        i,
        l;

    for (i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
        ref = data[i]['REFCODE'];
        desc = data[i]['DESCRIPTION'];
        col = data[i]['COLUMN_NAME'];

        if ($.inArray(ref, refCodes) === -1) {
            refCodes.push(ref);
        }
        if ($.inArray(desc, descriptions) === -1) {
            descriptions.push(desc);
        }
        if ($.inArray(col, columns) === -1) {
            columns.push(col);
        }
    }
};
```

This will give you the unique values in each array.

Comment: Works, just note that this is O(n2)

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653114/more-efficient-way-to-search-an-array-of-javascript-objects/4653168#4653168) explains a technique that can be adapted to your case

```js
var data = [{"REFCODE":"HIS","DESCRIPTION":"Hispanic or Latino","COLUMN_NAME":"MAT_ETHNICITY"},{"REFCODE":"NHIS","DESCRIPTION":"Not Hispanic or Latino","COLUMN_NAME":"MAT_ETHNICITY"},{"REFCODE":"UNK","DESCRIPTION":"Unknown","COLUMN_NAME":"MAT_ETHNICITY"},{"REFCODE":"AMERIND","DESCRIPTION":"American Indian/Alaska Native","COLUMN_NAME":"PAT_ETHNICITY"},{"REFCODE":"ASIAN","DESCRIPTION":"Asian","COLUMN_NAME":"PAT_ETHNICITY"},{"REFCODE":"HAW","DESCRIPTION":"Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander","COLUMN_NAME":"PAT_ETHNICITY"},{"REFCODE":"AA","DESCRIPTION":"Black or Africian American","COLUMN_NAME":"PAT_ETHNICITY"},{"REFCODE":"WHITE","DESCRIPTION":"White","COLUMN_NAME":"PAT_ETHNICITY"},{"REFCODE":"MORE","DESCRIPTION":"More than one race","COLUMN_NAME":"PAT_ETHNICITY"},{"REFCODE":"UNK","DESCRIPTION":"Unknown","COLUMN_NAME":"PAT_ETHNICITY"},{"REFCODE":"M","DESCRIPTION":"Male","COLUMN_NAME":"SEX"},{"REFCODE":"F","DESCRIPTION":"Female","COLUMN_NAME":"SEX"}];

function shallowClone(obj, exclude) {
  var clone = {};
  for (var prop in obj) {
    if (prop != exclude) {
      clone[prop] = obj[prop];
    }
  }
  return clone;
}

function mapFromArray (list , keyByProp, excludeKeyByProp) {
  var map = {};
  for (var i=0, item; item = list[i]; i++) {
    if ( !map[item[keyByProp]] ) {
      map[item[keyByProp]] = [];
    }
    map[item[keyByProp]].push(item);
  }
  
  if (excludeKeyByProp) {
    for (var prop in map) {
      map[prop] = map[prop].map(function(obj){
        return shallowClone(obj, keyByProp);
      });
    }
  }
  return map;
};


var separated = mapFromArray(data, 'COLUMN_NAME', true);
console.log(separated);
var pre = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre'));
pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(separated, null, 2);
```

**Before you explained what you needed for output in a comment, I answered with this**

[krillgar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28746412/227299) works. Here's one that is not O(n2) and does not contain duplicates.

```
var data = [/*your data */];
var refCodes = {}, descriptions = {}, columns = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    refCodes[data[i].REFCODE] = true;
    descriptions[data[i].DESCRIPTION] = true;
    columns[data[i].COLUMN_NAME] = true;
}

refCodes = Object.keys(refCodes);
descriptions = Object.keys(descriptions);
columns = Object.keys(columns);
```

And here's a generalization of that code

```js
var data = [{"REFCODE":"HIS","DESCRIPTION":"Hispanic or Latino","COLUMN_NAME":"MAT_ETHNICITY"},{"REFCODE":"NHIS","DESCRIPTION":"Not Hispanic or Latino","COLUMN_NAME":"MAT_ETHNICITY"},{"REFCODE":"UNK","DESCRIPTION":"Unknown","COLUMN_NAME":"MAT_ETHNICITY"},{"REFCODE":"AMERIND","DESCRIPTION":"American Indian/Alaska Native","COLUMN_NAME":"PAT_ETHNICITY"},{"REFCODE":"ASIAN","DESCRIPTION":"Asian","COLUMN_NAME":"PAT_ETHNICITY"},{"REFCODE":"HAW","DESCRIPTION":"Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander","COLUMN_NAME":"PAT_ETHNICITY"},{"REFCODE":"AA","DESCRIPTION":"Black or Africian American","COLUMN_NAME":"PAT_ETHNICITY"},{"REFCODE":"WHITE","DESCRIPTION":"White","COLUMN_NAME":"PAT_ETHNICITY"},{"REFCODE":"MORE","DESCRIPTION":"More than one race","COLUMN_NAME":"PAT_ETHNICITY"},{"REFCODE":"UNK","DESCRIPTION":"Unknown","COLUMN_NAME":"PAT_ETHNICITY"},{"REFCODE":"M","DESCRIPTION":"Male","COLUMN_NAME":"SEX"},{"REFCODE":"F","DESCRIPTION":"Female","COLUMN_NAME":"SEX"}];

function makeArraysFromProps(data) {
  var map = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var keys = Object.keys( data[i] );
    for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++ ) {
      var key = keys[j];
      if (!map[key]) {
        // Make it a map first to prevent duplicates without O(n2)
        map[key] = {};
      }
      map[key][ data[i][key] ] = true;
    }
  }
  var mapKeys = Object.keys(map);
  for (var k=0; k < mapKeys.length; k++) {
    map[mapKeys[k]] = Object.keys(map[mapKeys[k]]);
  }
  return map;
}


var separated = makeArraysFromProps(data);
console.log(separated);
var pre = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre'));
pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(separated, null, 2);
var separated = makeArraysFromProps(data);
console.log(separated);

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(separated)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with one SQL call and parse it client side. There is no point in doing three separate calls when you've got exactly what you need in one call.

Just loop through each object and then grab the property you want and stick it into a dropdown with Javascript.

I hope that was a sufficient answer.

EDIT:
Here is a way to extract the data which you can use. Then you can just populate an object with the different values and loop through that where ever you want.

```
var json = YOURJSONOBJECT;

var patObj = new Object;

json.forEach(function(data, i){ 
  if(data.COLUMN_NAME == 'PAT_ETHNICITY') {
    patObj[i] = { refCode: data.REFCODE, description: data.DESCRIPTION }
  }
  // Then add rest of your columns
});
```

Comment: or more simply `patbObj = jsonObj.filter(obj){ return obj.COLUMN_NAME ==  'PAT_ETHNICITY'}`

Comment: @JuanMendes  You have some errors in your snippet there. But yup, that's an even simpler way! `patObj = jsonObj.filter(function(obj){ return obj.COLUMN_NAME == 'PAT_ETHNICITY'  });`

Comment: I think the OP is actually asking about something else, display each column in a dropdown, so they want three arrays with the values from each property. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28746412/227299

Comment: This is closer to my needs because the three arrays need to be SEX, PAT_ENTICITY and MAT_ETHNICITY and not the REFCODE, DESCRIPTION and COLUMN_NAME

Comment: @user1314159 Now that the OP has clarified it in the comments, yea, this is closer

Comment: @user1314159 If it answered your question it would be awesome if you could mark it as the answer!