# Function to get index from an array of objects having certain value of provided property

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is based on and similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7176908/148271) but a little bit different because property name will be variable.

How do I create a function which will return me index of object having certain value of provided property?

```
function indexOf(propertyName,lookingForValue,array){
 //......

 return index;
}
```

So,

```
indexOf("token",123123,[
    {id_list:1, name:'Nick',token:'312312'},{id_list:2,name:'John',token:'123123'}
    ]);
```

should return 1.

The main problem I have is how do I check the property value when I have the property name as string with me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function indexOf(propertyName,lookingForValue,array) {
    for (var i in array) {
        if (array[i][propertyName] == lookingForValue) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

Edit: Please note that I do the loose type check '==' on purpose since you are giving an integer to this function whereas in the array the value you search for is a string.

Comment: Yes I needed loose type check only.

Answer (score 1):

I make a function which can be helpful to you. Check it.

```
function GetindexOf(propertyName,lookingForValue,array){
var obj = array;
for(o in obj)
{
   if(obj[o][propertyName] == lookingForValue)
   {
       //return index;
       alert("You have request for "+o+" index");
   }
 }
}
```