# Getting index of matching element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of elements in Javascript

```
var axes = [{id: "a"}, {id: "b"}]
```

and I have one of these items in a variable

```
var axis = {id: "b"}
```

I wanted a one liner in JavaScript (similar to the Linq one liners I can do in C#) where I will get the index of the array in which this element exists.  So, in this example I will get the answer 1.

How is this possible?

Comment: `{id="b"}` isn't proper JavaScript. You want `{id:"b"}`.

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258077/how-to-find-index-of-an-object-by-key-and-value-in-an-javascript-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array prototype `map` method:

```
var axisIndex = axes.map(function(x) {return x.id; }).indexOf(axis.id);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16100446/1414562

And to support older browsers, you could use the jQuery's way:

```
var axisIndex = $.inArray(axis.id, $.map(axes, function(x){return x.id}));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to create a new `axis` object that looks the same as one of the elements in the `axes` array, but isn't actually an element of the `axes` array. If this is the case, the `indexOf` method won't work because it would expect to find the exact object you're searching for in the array.

There are ways of doing this - it would usually involve more than one line though (the one line restriction seems fairly trivial). However, I've found a solution, despite it looking rather ugly, and better suited to a code golfing problem than real live code.

`axes.indexOf(axes.filter(function(el) {if (el.id === axis.id) return true; }).shift());`