# How can I return an Index location for an item in a JSON array by searching with text?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Here is my JSON array:

```
var planets = [{
  "Name": "Mercury",
  "Temperature": "427°C",
  "Position" : 1
}, {
  "Name": "Venus",
  "Temperature": "462°C",
  "Position" : 2

}, {
  "Name": "Earth",
  "Temperature": "16°C",
  "Position" : 3
}]
```

Using the text "Earth" is there a method that would return me the index location of the item Earth in my Planets array?

For example:

```
planets.find("Earth")
```

Comment: 1. This is a JavaScript _object_ (or more specifically, an array) not a JSON array. JSON = literally text format that would represent JS objects. 2. You can use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) but it's not well supported everywhere yet. If you don't need the _index_ but the actual _object_, then just use straight `find`

Comment: related - http://stackoverflow.com/q/15997879/104380

Comment: related - http://stackoverflow.com/q/10557486/104380

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var index = -1;
var val = 'Earth';
var filteredObj = planets.find(function(item, i){
  if(item.Name === val){
    index = i;
    return i;
  }
});

console.log(index, filteredObj);
```

Comment: I'll assume data would be 'planets' in my case?

Answer (score 2):

Plain JS: [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

> The findIndex() method returns an index in the array, if an element in
>   the array satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise -1 is
>   returned.

```
[{
  "Name": "Mercury",
  "Temperature": "427°C",
  "Position" : 1
}, {
  "Name": "Venus",
  "Temperature": "462°C",
  "Position" : 2

}, {
  "Name": "Earth",
  "Temperature": "16°C",
  "Position" : 3
}].findIndex(x => x.Name === "Earth")
```

If you're in IE 9+, you can however use the [reduce function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each
>   value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single
>   value.

```
[{
  "Name": "Mercury",
  "Temperature": "427°C",
  "Position" : 1
}, {
  "Name": "Venus",
  "Temperature": "462°C",
  "Position" : 2

}, {
  "Name": "Earth",
  "Temperature": "16°C",
  "Position" : 3
}].reduce(function (foundSoFar, x, i) { // Note no arrow funcion
  if (foundSoFar < 0 && x.Name === "Earth") {
    return i;
  } else {
    return foundSoFar;
  }
}, -1);
```

Alternatively, use an implementation of a library like [ramda](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#findIndex)

Comment: what is findIndex? where does it comes from? can you explain?

Comment: This is a great answer but the linked article suggests you won't get any support from IE.

Comment: @AdamWaselnuk how about now?

Comment: Great use of reduce :)

Answer (score 1):

with regular js:

```
function getIndexOfPlanet(name){
  for( var i in planets )
    if( planets[i].Name == name )
       return i;

}
```

Using Lodash utility method [**findIndex**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#findIndex), it's as easy as:

```js
var planets = [{
  "Name"        : "Mercury",
  "Temperature" : "427°C",
  "Position"    : 1
}, {
  "Name"        : "Venus",
  "Temperature" : "462°C",
  "Position"    : 2
}, {
  "Name"        : "Earth",
  "Temperature" : "16°C",
  "Position"    : 3
}]

function getIndexOfPlanet(name){
  return _.findIndex(planets, { 'Name':name});
}

console.log( getIndexOfPlanet('Earth') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) `index` of the current element being processed in the array:

```js
var planets = [{"Name": "Mercury","Temperature": "427°C","Position": 1}, {"Name": "Venus","Temperature": "462°C","Position": 2}, {"Name": "Earth","Temperature": "16°C","Position": 3}],
    earthIndex = -1,
    earth = planets.find(function(item, index) {
        if (item.Name === 'Earth') {
            earthIndex = index;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

console.log('Earth index is:', earthIndex);
```

Comment: This is going to be more widely supported than `findIndex`. I suppose the only change I'd make is to return `-1` if the element is not found as that would make it behave more like a `findIndex` function but that might or might not be relevant for different use cases.

Answer (score 1):

var locationIndex;
  planets.forEach(function(ele,ind){if(ele.Name === "Earth") locationIndex = ind;});
  console.log(locationIndex);

find or findIndex may not support some browsers like IE..