# Javascript indexOf object not found

Tags: javascript, indexof

I'm trying to find the index of my object inside an array in Javascript.

This is the code I'm using, **this returns -1 so it's not found. But it's there**

```
var index = this.state.users.indexOf(user);
```

The object I'm comparing with is identical to the one's in the collection as shown in the picture below

[image]

I'm using this code to compare the two

```
console.log(this.state.users[0]);
console.log(member);
```

So I don't understand why this is giving a negative result

Comment: So, just to be clear, you want to find the index of an `Object` in `Array`?

Comment: Maybe you can try something like this
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7178381/5182914

Comment: Hi, The following worked for me, the filter function https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/3fv2ou/remove_an_object_with_an_id_from_a_collection_of/cts75n5

Comment: I added my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

In javascript object compared by reference, such as

```
var obj1 = {prop: 0};
var obj2 = {prop: 0};
alert(obj1 === obj2); //false
```

`indexOf` compare like this, so it isn't finding anything.

To find object in array *identical* to given, you can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

Or ecmascript 2015 [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method

Answer (score 2):

Array indexOf uses STRICT EQUALITY (===)

so

```
var v1 = {id:1, info:{something:'else'}};
var v2 = {id:2, info:{something:'else'}};
var v3 = {id:1, info:{something:'else'}};
var v4 = v2;
var arr = [v1, v2];
arr.indexOf(v2); // 1
arr.indexOf(v3); // -1
arr.indexOf(v4); // 1
```

even though v3 looks just like v1, it's not v1

so it depends on how the object you are trying to find is related to the objects in the array

Answer (score 0):

IndexOf function is used to find an occurrence of a string in another one.

When this occurrence is not found, the function return -1.

Please refer to this website for more informations :

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Comment: `Array.prototype.indexOf` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Sorry mistyped the title, I know that -1 is not found, but it's there as shown in the screenshots, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It returns -1 if it never occurs.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Comment: `Array.prototype.indexOf` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Sorry mistyped the title, I know that -1 is not found, but it's there as shown in the screenshots, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It uses strict comparison to find member in the users array.

What it means is that if it will return `-1` if for every entry in your array `member !== theUserYouAreLookingFor` (which is the case when variables are not holding reference to the same object, not similar but the same object in memory).

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom function for something like this, in which you pass the array you want to search in, the object you want to find the index for and a **unique property** of the object:

```
var indexOfArrayObject = function(arr, obj, prop) {
    var index = -1;
    arr.some(function(val, ind){
        if(val[prop] === obj[prop]) {
            index = ind;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return index;
}

// Getting the index by 'id'
var userIndex = indexOfArrayObject(this.state.users, user, 'id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, in JavaScript, `{ a: 1 } === { a: 1 }` or `{ a: 1 } == { a: 1 }` is **false**.

In your environment, you'll also find that `this.state.users[0] === member` is **false** too.

So, the method you're using for comparison is not correct.