# Searching array with multiple keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can see this works fine for searching a simple array:

```
var arr1 = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
var index1 = arr1.indexOf('d');
console.log("index1:" + index1); // index1:3
```

When I try to do the same thing for a different kind of array, it doesn't find the "jane" value:

```
var arr2 = [{"id":0,"name":"petty"},{"id":1,"name":"jane"},{"id":2,"name":"with"}];
var index2 = arr2.indexOf('jane');
console.log("index2:" + index2); // index2:-1
```

Sorry - I realise I am probably missing something obvious. I have searched on SO / google for searching multi dimensional arrays, but I don't even know if the array in the 2nd example is a 2d / multi dimensional array, so I am probably not searching for the right thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get index of object by its property in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176908/how-to-get-index-of-object-by-its-property-in-javascript)

Comment: `arr2` is not multi dimensional array but it is array of objects, notice the `{}`, it means object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findIndex()` method to find index of object with specific value.

```js
var arr = [{"id":0,"name":"petty"},{"id":1,"name":"jane"},{"id":2,"name":"with"}];

var index = arr.findIndex(e => e.name == 'jane')
console.log("index: " + index);
```

Comment: I'd like to note that `findIndex` was added only in ECMAScript 2015, and it is not compatible with some browsers (esp. Internet Explorer). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Answer (score 0):

First of all: it's not a multi-dimensional array. It's an array consisting of objects. It's one-dimensional. To find an object you need to iterate through an array and check the needed key, e.g.:

```
arr.findIndex(function(el) { return el.name === 'jane' })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check all values of the objects and use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) instead of [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```js
var arr2 = [{ id: 0, name: "petty" }, { id: 1, name: "jane" }, { id: 2, name: "with" }],
    index2 = arr2.findIndex(o => Object.values(o).some(v => v === 'jane'));

console.log(index2);
```

Comment: Nested iterators/generators seem pretty inefficient, as Nenad already posted. This will be better: `arr.findIndex(e => e.name == 'jane')`

Comment: @JonasLibbrecht, right, but only if you know the key in advance.

Comment: @ Nina Scholz, that's correct but then you are performing a needle in a haystack search and that's basically inefficient on it's own and should not be implemented like this. That issue would be better solved with binary trees or something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [{"id":0,"name":"petty"},{"id":1,"name":"jane"},{"id":2,"name":"with"}];
arr.findIndex((item)=>{return item.name=="petty"})
//output is 0
```