# Array.indexOf isnt a function

Tags: react-redux, react-tsx

The app i made is a movie website that shows movies based on your search. You can also add favorites, however its not linked to your profile. So the solution i came up with was to make another value in the profile initial state in redux.

```
export const profileInitialState = [
{pass: '123', user: 'daniel', email: 'daniel@123.com', favourites: 'batman' },
]

interface IProfileState {
    pass: string, 
    user: string,
    email: string,
    favourites?: string
}
```

and just map it from there

```
{data.profileReducer.slice(data.profileReducer.indexOf( {user: currUser, pass: password, email: email}, 1)).map(info =>
  <p key={data.profileReducer.length + 1.5} > {info.favourites} </p>)}
```

and even thought it works perfectly in the console, it tell me profileReducer.indexOf is not a function when i implement it in my code.

Comment: Try to log `data.profileReducer`, e.g: `console.log(data.profileReducer)`, it could be null, or undefined. also make sure it is an array.

Comment: i logged it and it is an array, but it is also undefined next to the state interface in the reducer  **const profileReducer: (state: IProfileState[] | undefined, action: ActionTypes)**

Comment: If you add this: `console.log(data.profileReducer)`, what would be the the result in browser console?

Comment: `Array[ Object ]` was returned when console logging it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `Array.prototype.indexOf()` can't be used to find the index of object elements in the array.

[How to get index of object by its property in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176908/how-to-get-index-of-object-by-its-property-in-javascript/54015295). This link describes how you can get the index of array elements.

The error can be caused by a few reasons

- data.profileReduceris undefinded or null
- data.profileReducer is not an array