# How can I get object in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Example i have this:

```
'[{
   "_id" : ObjectId("ewfg4wefewefefw"),
   "student":
   [{
       "_id" : ObjectId("rvro43jroorvke"),
       "fname": "someone"
       "score": 3.5
   },
   {
      "_id" : ObjectId("fnoierlj4e"),
      "fname": "random"
      "score": 3.5
   },
   {
      "_id" : ObjectId("f32023wkjlew"),
      "fname": "the one"
      "score": 3.5
   }]
}]'
```

and I only want the result is the the one:

```
'{
   "_id" : ObjectId("f32023wkjlew"),
   "fname": "the one"
   "score": 3.5
}'
```

I think this situation is get object inside array. I tried to serach few place and cant find the one working for me. I am using monk to connect to db.

Comment: You can iterate the array and get one by one. BTW your expectation is not valid JSON either you can convert in object or use one by one

Answer (score 0):

To access an element of an array you have to call arrName[index starting at 0]. Try student[2]

Comment: What if i dont know the index. and I only know the objectID

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166765/search-json-array-for-matching-attribute) out