# JavaScript How to filter array of objects by dynamic key?

Tags: javascript

I have an array which contains objects with dynamic keys, my aim is to find if this array contains or not specific key, How can this be achieved?

```js
let arr = [
  {item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }},
  {item2: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }},
  {item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }}
]

let target = 'item1'

//result array
 let arr = [
  {item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }},
]
```

Comment: A key for the object, or a key as in the `key: 'sdfd'`?

Comment: So from your new edit, I assume you want to return the object with that key?

Comment: @MrMythical yes, I want to return object with that key

Comment: Please try: `let targetArr = arr.filter(o => !!o[target]);` and share your feedback.

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166765/search-an-array-for-matching-attribute/62792400#62792400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

You need to use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method on the array, the `filter` method takes 1 argument which a function run on each item to decide should the item included in filtered result.

```js
const filtered = array.filter(function (item) {
  return true  // mean the item included in filtered result
  return false // mean the item not included in filtered result
})
```

Then we need [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) to know are the
dynamic key was in the object.

Example : `key in object` (returns boolean).

### Answer

```js
const filteredArray = array.filter(function (object) {
  if (dynamicKey in object) { // if the object contains the dynamic key
    return true;              // include the object in filtered result
  } else {        // or else
    return false; // don't include the object in filtered result
  }
})
```

The code can be shorten by using [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and just return value with what `in` operator gives.

```js
const filteredArray = array.filter(object => dynamicKey in object)
```

### Example

```js
const array = [
  { item1: { key: 'sdfd', value: 'sdfd' } },
  { item2: { key: 'sdfd', value: 'sdfd' } },
  { item3: { key: 'sdfd', value: 'sdfd' } }
]

const dynamicKey = 'item1'

const filteredArray = array.filter(object => dynamicKey in object)

console.log('filtered array :', filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator

```js
let arr = [
  {item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }},
  {item2: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }},
  {item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }}
]

let target = 'item1'

console.log(
  arr.filter(i => target in i)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your title, I assume you want to try using `array.filter` , so follow up your attempt of using `array.filter`, this is an opion:

```js
let arr = [
  {item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }},
  {item2: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }},
  {item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }}
]

let target = 'item1'

let newarr= arr.filter(each=>Object.keys(each).toString() ==target)
console.log(newarr)
```

Comment: Why would you compare an array with a string?

Comment: @MrMythical, I am not comparing the array to string. I am comparing the object(keys) (string) of each object of the target (string)

Comment: But `Object.keys()` returns an array, and `target` is a string... This is why strict equality is much more preferred

Comment: @MrMythical, gosh, doesn't realize that before. Thanks for teaching me that! I have add `toString()` to make sure, but I think even if Object.keys() is an array, it will still work

Comment: But even with `.toString()`, if there is so much as another key, it will be broken. It worked before because it automatically tries to convert. I just have to say this is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has built-in functions that return the object's keys for you:

```
var x = {
    name : "Romulo",
    age : 17
}

console.log(Object.keys(x))
```

Output:

```
["name","age"]
```

This returns an array, you just need check if your key is in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.filter method and Object.hasOwn method for this, please never use the `in` operator it has some precedence issues.

```js
const arr = [
    {item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }},
    {item2: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }},
    {item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }}
]

function filterByKey(list, target) {
    return list.filter(
        item => Object.hasOwn(item, target)
    );
}

const target = "item1";

console.log(
    filterByKey(arr, target)
);
```